# Adding a third dimension on a 2D heatmap

Tags: r

I am wondering if you could help me out with the following question:

I have a correlation matrix and a third variable (continuous) for every possible pair in the correlation matrix.

Here is a toy example:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000,2,1)
y <- 0.1*x+rnorm(1000,1,1)
z <- y+rnorm(1000)
third.dimension <- c("(x,y)" = 0.3, "(x,z)" = 0.5, "(y,z)"= 1)
my.df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

First, I want to create a heatmap of that correlation matrix which I do with

```
heatmap(cor(my.df))
```

Next, I would like to have a coloured dot within each "cell" of the heatmap, depending on the value of the third dimension for the respective pair. Example - if the value is between 0 and 0.49, I have a black dot, if it is between 0.5 and 1, a grey dot etc.

Hence, where I have the correlation between z and y, say, I would have a grey dot painted in the corresponding "cell" of the correlation matrix.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This is much easier to do with `image`. Do you need the dendrogram?

Comment: I don't need the dendrogram at all Marc! Do you have any tip on how to input that said third "dimension" on the coloured matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000,2,1)
y <- 0.1*x+rnorm(1000,1,1)
z <- y+rnorm(1000)
third.dimension <- c("(x,y)" = 0.3, "(x,z)" = 0.5, "(y,z)"= 1)
my.df <- data.frame(x,y,z)


# required function
val2col <- function(z, zlim, col = heat.colors(12), breaks){
 if(!missing(breaks)){
  if(length(breaks) != (length(col)+1)){stop("must have one more break than color")}
 }
 if(missing(breaks) & !missing(zlim)){
  breaks <- seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out=(length(col)+1)) 
 }
 if(missing(breaks) & missing(zlim)){
  zlim <- range(z, na.rm=TRUE)
  breaks <- seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out=(length(col)+1))
 }
 CUT <- cut(z, breaks=breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)
 colorlevels <- col[match(CUT, levels(CUT))] # assign colors to heights for each point
 return(colorlevels)
}


# plot
COR <- list(
  x = seq(ncol(my.df)),
  y = seq(ncol(my.df)),
  z = cor(my.df)
)

image(COR, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(1, at=COR$x, labels = names(my.df))
axis(2, at=COR$x, labels = names(my.df))
box()

COR$col <- val2col(c(COR$z), col = grey.colors(21), zlim=c(0,1))
points(expand.grid(x=COR$x, y=COR$y), col=COR$col, pch=16, cex=3)
```

[image]